# Generate an array of N random integers, between 1 and K, but containing at least one of each number

Tags: python, numpy, random

I need to generate a matrix of **`N`** random integers between `1` and `K`, where each number appears at least once, having **`K ≤ N`**.

I have no problem using a call to `numpy.random.random_integers()` and checking the number of distinct elements, when `K` is much less than `N`, but it's harder to get a valid array when `K` approximates to `N`.

Is there any nice way to get this done? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Then you don't really have `N` random integers. You have `N` - `K` random integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any built in functionality, but you could always make the exact array you want and shuffle/reshape.

Something like,

```
raw_array = np.append(np.arange(1, K+1), np.random.randint(1, K+1, size=(N-K)))
np.random.shuffle(raw_array)
```

This guarantees you have 1 to K from your arange, then the remaining required numbers (N - K) are filled by a random number from 1 to K.

Edited to specifically get 1 through K, rather than 0 to K - 1.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't thought this before. Works as expected, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fill the matrix iteratively with numbers 1-K so if K was 2, and N was 4, [1,2,1,2]. Then randomly generate 2 random numbers between 1-N where the numbers don't equal, and swap the numbers at those positions.

Comment: Thank you, while is not what I was looking for, it's close.

Answer (score 1):

Fill K numbers using xrange(k) and then fill (n-k) number using random number generator

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `np.random.choice(N, size=K, replace=False)`, [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice), which will return `K` distinct numbers up to `N`.

Comment: This doesn't work because I need an array of N integers, between 1 and K. This produces an array of K integers between 1 and N.
Swapping variables doesn't help tho because the first argument must be bigger than size, which is not what I have. Anyway thanks!
Swapping variables doesn't help thoi